# No common roots of complex polynomial and of its derivative

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

**Our specific context**
Here is our specific contour integral

$$\int_{\Gamma_{0}}F\big(\sum_{w:p_{z}(w)=0}\frac{1}{w^{a}}\frac{1}{n+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{v_{j}}{w-v_{j}}}         \big)\frac{dz}{z},$$

where F is an analytic nonlinear function with very nice bounds (eg. some determinant quantity) and

$$R_{z}:=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: p_{z}(w):=w^{n-m}\prod_{i=1}^{m}(w-v_{i})-z^{n}=0\}$$

for naturals $n>m>0, a>0$ and complex $v_{i}\in \mathbb{C}$.

For this contour integral to be well-defined the contour $\Gamma_{0}$ has to contain the pole $z=0$ and also it has to prohibit the factor 
$$\frac{1}{n+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{v_{j}}{w-v_{j}}} $$

from blowing up. That is, $\Gamma_{0}$ must be chosen so that for any $z\in \Gamma_{0}$, the $p_{z}(w)$ and the above factor don't share any common roots. We call this a *well-defined choice*.
So we have the extra freedom to have any contour shapes we want that will achieve this goal. Here is our full question for our work:

> $Q_0$: Is it possible to make two *well-defined choices* of contour $\Gamma_{0,1},\Gamma_{0,2}$  that satisfy the following property: for $z\in \Gamma_{0,1}$ the $w\in R_{z}$ satisfies
>   $$|v_{j}|>|w|, \text{ for all }1\leq j\leq m$$
>   for $z\in \Gamma_{0,2}$ the $w\in R_{z}$ satisfies

$$|v_{j}|<|w|, \text{ for all }1\leq j\leq m.$$

I realize this question is very technical and so I list here some other questions that will be helpful in this direction.

**On-going progress and questions**

Consider contour $\Gamma_{0}\in  \mathbb{C}$ around zero. For fixed point $z_{0}\in \Gamma_{0}$ consider the root set

$$R_{z_0}:=\{w\in \mathbb{C}: p_{z}(w):=w^{n-m}\prod_{i=1}^{m}(w-v_{i})-z_{0}^{n}=0\}$$

for naturals $n>m>0$ and complex $v_{i}\in \mathbb{C}$.

How to find "optimal" constraints on $\Gamma_{0},\{v_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m}$ and the ratio $n/m$ such that the w-derivative of $p_{z_{0}}(w)$ is not zero if $w\in R_{z_0}$

$$p_{0}'(w)=p'_{z_0}(w)=w^{n-m-1}\prod_{i=1}^{m}(w-v_{i})(n+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{v_{j}}{w-v_{j}})\neq 0(*)$$.

> Q1: Are there necessary and sufficient conditions to ensure (*)? Or very sharp ones?

A sufficient one is to consider the circular contour $\Gamma_{0}$ with radius $|z_0|>(1+\frac{m}{n})max(|v_{i}|)$ (because then that gives $|n+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{v_{j}}{w-v_{j}}|\neq 0$). Another condition that works is inspired from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912568/if-pz-is-a-monic-polynomial-then-pzb-z-z-1z-z-2-cdots-z-z-n/912570#912570), namely if we set
$$-z_{0}^{n}=b=\epsilon+\max_{p_{0}'(w)=0}|p_{0}(w)|$$

even for small $\epsilon>0$, then $p_{z_{0}},p_{z_{0}}'$ won't share common roots. So just take the contour with modulus
$$|z_{0}|^{n}=\epsilon+max_{p_{0}'(w)=0}|p_{0}(w)|$$
and use reverse triangle inequality to show that when $p_{0}'(w)=0$ we have
$$|p_{z_{0}}(w)|=|p_{0}(w)-z_{0}^{n}|>\epsilon>0$$
and so $p_{z_{0}},p_{z_{0}}'$ don't share common roots.

> Q2: But can we say anything concrete about $\max_{p_{0}'(w)=0}|p_{0}(w)|$ ? Does it have any formula (or sharp bounds) in terms of $\{v_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m}$ and $n,m$?

But I was hoping for a necessary and sufficient one. Or any ideas for sharper ones? Any help will be much appreciated.

Maybe something to do with resultants? [Polynomial with no common roots with its first and second derivatives](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111483/polynomial-with-no-common-roots-with-its-first-and-second-derivatives?rq=1)

> Q3: If the above is doable (i.e. the contour and the constants can be chosen so that the polynomial and its first derivative have no common roots), can we also obtain the following: for each fix $1\leq j\leq m$, then can we perturb the contour $\Gamma_{0}$ so that if $w\in R_{z_{0}}, $ with $z_{0}\in \Gamma_{0}$, we can also guarrantee

$$|v_{j}|>|w| (**)?$$

The question Q3 is the main one I am concerned about. The first condition I wrote with max of $v_i$ fails simply because if $w\in R_{z}$, then you can show that
$$|w|>|z|$$
and so 
$$|w|>|z|>(1+\frac{m}{n})max(|v_{i}|)>|v_{j}|.$$
But I am curious if the second condition in terms of max over roots, helps with getting (**).

> Q4: Can we say anything about the roots $w$ of

$$n+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{v_{j}}{w-v_{j}}=0?$$
This will be very helpful. The motivation is studying Bethe roots for a particular system.

Comment: Right now, as the question is written, the contour $\Gamma_0$ plays no role and is a distraction. Did you mean to say the $v$'s are constrained to be inside the (simple) contour? Even that would be useless, unless for instance the contour had to be a circle which would work well with the behind-the-scenes action of the Moebius group.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam I added our specific context. Here the contour  $\Gamma_{0}$  can be any shape that will achieve the goal of having well-defined contour integral. Indeed, in most case the circular contour choice was good enough, but I want to provide the full context in case other contour shapes to make sure the contour integral is well-defined.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Is it better now? Thank you for your comment, I upvoted it.

Comment: Version #20 of this post.