# Roots for $p(w)=n+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{v_{j}}{w-v_{j}}$

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Let $v_{j}\in \mathbb{C}, 1\leq j\leq m$ and $w\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{v_{j}\}_{j=1}^{m}$ and $n>0$.

> Q: Can we say anything about the m roots $w_{1},...,w_{m}$ of

$$p(w)=n+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{v_{j}}{w-v_{j}}=0?$$

Can we say anything about their approximate location in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{v_{j}\}_{j=1}^{m}$ for a fixed collection of $\{v_{j}\}_{j=1}^{m}$.  Does studying the roots of such functions fall under any framework? (incidentally, in case it helps to ring any bells, the antiderivative has a nice form
$$wn+log(\prod_{j=1}^{m}(w-v_{j})^{v_{j}})+constants)$$

Do we have a formula for these roots? Do we know their location with respect to the constants $\{v_{j}\}_{j=1}^{m}$?

> Q2: Supposing that $v_j$ are distant enough from each other, are the roots $w_j$ within some disjoint disks centered at each of the $v_j$ eg. do we have $w_{j}\in B_{r_{j}}(v_{j})$ for some radii collection $(r_{j})_{j=1}^{m}$? Is there a way to use resultants techniques like mentioned in the answer below to help with this Q2?
>
> Q3: Has that equation shown up in more recent times in some context? It is very reminiscent of equations from random matrix theory, Coulomb log-gases.

This will be very helpful in a different question [No common roots of complex polynomial and of its derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362060/no-common-roots-of-complex-polynomial-and-of-its-derivative).

The motivation is studying Bethe roots for a particular system.

Update: just to be clear the question is still open. I think even just answering Q2 in the positive/negative will be very interesting.

Comment: First of all, what you wrote is not a polynomial. Second, $p(w)=0$ is equivalent to a polynomial equation of degree $m$. Therefore, there are $m$, counting multiplicity. This answers one of your questions. Concerning the rest, it is unclear what exactly do you want to know about these roots.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Is it better now? I am just looking for information about their location with respect to the location of the constants $\{v_{j}\}_{j=1}^{m}$.

Comment: If you multiply all the $v_j$ by some large factor, you can get them as far apart as you want, but the effect on the roots is simply to multiply them by the same factor. You can say more if the $v_j$ are real. Between two real $v_j$ of the same sign, $p$ changes its sign, so there must be a root in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexandre said, there is not enough guidance to as to what kind of info about these equations the OP is after. In any case, something of interest for equations given in the above form is that there is a nice formula for the resultant of two such equations. It involves the *matrix-tree theorem*. The formula was [discovered](https://eudml.org/doc/147779) by Borchardt and then was [rediscovered](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s2-6.1.468) by A. L. Dixon.

Comment: is it better now? I am just looking for any geometric information about these roots $w_1, ...., w_m$ for fixed collection of constants $v_j$. For example, are these roots close to disks centered at each of the $v_j$?

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted.

Comment: I think the formula for the resultant should help.

Comment: It is a bit different because they don't have the constant n. But it would be interesting to know how to use that resultant deteminantal formula to study the roots of the above rational function? Is it possible to give some details? thank you

Comment: Maybe I have to find some other rational function whose roots are more manageable, and then compute the resultant with the one from the post? So as to help me pinpoint the relative location of the roots $(w_j)_{j=1}^{m}$ with respect to $(v_j)_{j=1}^{m}$.